# Applying CSS to php variable

Tags: php, css

I have a PHP function with the following line:

```
print ' <span class="highlight">SALE!: </span><span>£</span>'.$sxml[sales_price_inc];
```

I need to apply this CSS style:

```
style="text-decoration:line-through;
```

to the

```
.$sxml[sales_price_inc]
```

variable text it prints

Comment: Wrap it in `<span>` with the style you want.

Comment: What does the variable consist? Why not wrapping it with a styled div/span?

Comment: Why do I have so many downvotes?

Comment: I didn't down vote this but... This question seems fairly localized - how could you make it applicable to more scenarios?  It seems like you could have shown more research - what did you try already?  Also, it would be easier for the reader if you explicitly stated your question - "How do I apply the CSS to this element?" for example.

Comment: OK, seems a bit unfair, i'm a complete beginner at PHP. I do not really know other scenarios as such. I tried various things to try to get this work but wasn't able to achieve the result. It seems obvious now but not at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print ' <span class="highlight">SALE!: </span><span>£</span><span style="text-decoration:line-through;">'.$sxml[sales_price_inc].'</span>';
```

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap your text with a span, and just have the style variable:

```
$style = "text-decoration:line-through;";
print ' <span class="highlight">SALE!: </span><span>£</span><span style="' . $style . '">' . $sxml['sales_price_inc'] . '</span>';
```